# FIWARE : Errors when dealing with Locale caracters (french for instance) as Payload

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, french

I am currently testing some SmartDataModels (SmartDestination/Events), and when I try to add an entity in which the description contains some french caracters like "é" or "à", the Orion CB rejects my payload with the following error message :

*entityCreate009 400 Bad Request {"error":"BadRequest","description":"Invalid characters in attribute value"}*

... because it contains an "é"

The tested JSON payload (NGSI v2) is this one : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smart-data-models/dataModel.TourismDestinations/2ab2bac0fae5893ba4310714823e293c9030f8c1/Event/examples/example.json

Do I need to provide specific option in order to deal with Locale caracters ?

Many thanks in advance for your help
Rgds
Laurent

Answer (score 1):

Some characters are not allowed in attribute value in order to avoid script injections attack in some circumstances. The set of forbidden characters is described [in Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/forbidden_characters/index.html).

Note "é" or "à" are not in this list, but probably you are using some other that is forbidden and you are getting the error due to this reason.

You can use attribute type `TextUnrestricted` to avoid this Orion protection mechanism. But use it at your own risk! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do confirm that I am not using any of the restricted caracters.

Comment: Hello, I would be interested to know how text is encoded in the message payload. For instance, I have got a string with a telephone number like +33 0 (6) 00 00 00 11.   The parenthesis are refused by Orion. I have tested to encode the parenthesis using unicode syntax  : \u0028 but it does not work.   Is there a way to properly encode this kind of characters ?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recomendation is to use URL encode (assuming of course that the consumer of that information can to the dual URL decode operation)

Comment: I have fixed the issue by the using the following version of the Orion CB : {
  "orionld version": "0.8.0",
  "orion version":   "1.15.0-next",
  "uptime":          "1 d, 0 h, 29 m, 14 s",
  "git_hash":        "nogitversion",
  "compile_time":    "Fri May 28 09:25:13 UTC 2021",
  "compiled_by":     "root",
  "compiled_in":     "buildkitsandbox",
  "release_date":    "Fri May 28 09:25:13 UTC 2021",
  "doc":             "https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/master/"
}